# Can't get md-autocomplete to display on the page as it does in the angular-material example

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I've been able to hook up angular materials autocomplete directive up to my data source and to display the information that I want, however I am unable to make the list of results display in the same way it does here:

https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete

My results appear like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLjio.png

Also, when I click away from the search box the autocomplete suggestions disappear and do not reappear on refocusing.

My HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="RoutesCtrl as ctrl" id="mainDiv" layout="column">
  <div layout="row" flex>
    <div layout="column" flex id="content">
    <md-content>
      <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools header-color">
          <md-button class="md-fab md-primary button-color" >
            <md-icon class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope md-default-theme hamburger-icon" aria-label="Menu" style="height: 14px; width: 14px;" md-svg-src="/assets/icons/ic_menu_18px.svg"></md-icon>
          </md-button>
          <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings"></md-button>
          <h1 class="md-display-4"></h1>
        </div>
      </md-toolbar>
    </md-content>
    <md-content layout-padding layout="column">
      <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
        <md-autocomplete
        md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
        md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
        md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
        md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
        md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
        md-item-text="item.from_where + ' to ' + item.to_where"
        placeholder="Search for a route"
        md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
        ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
        md-min-length="3"
        md-delay="0"
        md-autoselect="true">

        <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.from_where + ' to ' + item.to_where}}</span>
        </md-autocomplete>
      </form>
    </md-content>
    <div ng-controller="MapController">
      <leaflet center="center"></leaflet>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The html that mine generates does not have the ng-focus attribute or the class "ng-scope".

The service I am using to grab my data:

```
App.service('route',  function route($http, $q){
    var route = this;
    route.routeList = {};

    route.getAllRoutes = function(){
        var defer = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/routes')
                .success(function(response){
                    route.routeList = response;
                    defer.resolve(response);
                })
                .error(function(error, status){
                    defer.reject(error);
                });

        return defer.promise;
    };
    return route;
});
```

And the controller:

```
App.controller("RoutesCtrl", function($scope, route, $timeout, $q, $log, $http){

    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.getAll();
    };




    $scope.getAll = function(){
        route.getAllRoutes()
                .then(function(response){
                    //success

                    self.routes = response;
                    return route.routeList;
                }, function(error) {
                    //error
                }, function(message) {
                    //message
                });
    };

    var self = this;
    self.searchText = null;
    self.querySearch = querySearch;
    self.simulateQuery = true;
    self.isDisabled = false;
    self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
    self.searchTextChange = searchTextChange;
    self.selectedItem = null;

    function querySearch (q) {
        var results = q ? self.routes.filter(createFilterFor(q) ) : [],
                deferred;
        if (self.simulateQuery) {
            deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function() { deferred.resolve( results ); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
        return deferred.promise;
        } else {
            return results;
        }
    }
    function searchTextChange (text) {
        $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
    }
    function createFilterFor(query) {
        var lowerCaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
        return function FilterFn(route) {
            return (route.route_from_to.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseQuery) === 0);
        };
    }
    function selectedItemChange (item) {
        if (!item) {
            return
        } else {
            console.log(self.selectedItem);
            $log.info('Item changed to ' + item.route_from_to);
        }

    }


    $scope.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by angular-material 0.8.3. Updating to the latest release fixed it.

Answer (score -4):

change attribute:
**placeholder**="Search for a route"
to
**md-floating-label**="Search for a route"

Comment: **Placeholder** and **md-floating-label** are different attributes for different purposes.